# Reduce too many if clause

Tags: python

I have created a script to calculate day of the week, but I have to use too many if clause. Is there a way to do this without using too many ifs.

Actual link

http://pc2solution.blogspot.in/2014/09/python-calculate-day-of-week-for-any.html

Script:

```
import datetime
year = raw_input('Enter year in format YYYY... ')
mon = raw_input('Enter month in format MM ')
date = raw_input('Enter date in format ')
a = datetime.date(int(year), int(mon), int(date)).weekday()  # 3=Thursday
if a == 0:
    print 'Its Monday'
if a == 1:
    print 'Its Tuesday'
if a == 2:
    print 'Its Wednesday'
if a == 3:
    print 'Its Thursday'
if a == 4:
    print 'Its Friday'
if a == 5:
    print 'Its Saturday'
if a == 6:
    print 'Its Sunday'
```

Comment: [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Or don't bother at all; use `strftime` and the `%A` directive: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 2):

Using dictionary will solve your `if` problem. However, it's worth mentioning that you don't need to reinvent the wheel, you can simply use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

I would like also to mention [`Arrow`](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) which enables better dates and times for Python, try it.

Comment: Update with `date.strftime('%A')` and this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a dictionary keyed by number with the day names as values and then index it to get what you want. Something like this

```
d = { 0 : "Monday",
      1 : "Tuesday",
      .
      .
      .
    }

print "It's {}".format(d[a])
```

Answer (score 1):

The no-dictionary way:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.date(2014,9,2)
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(a, '%A')
'Tuesday'
```

Comment: +1. Much more sensible as a solution to the question asked but I think the OP was asking about implementing a switch type statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dictionary that its key will be day index and its values the string you want to show

```
verbose_dict = {0: "Its Monday", 1 : "Its Tuesday", 2: "Its Wednesday", 3: "Its Thursday", 4: "Its Friday", 5: "Its Saturday", 6: "Its Sunday" }
a = datetime.date(int(year), int(mon), int(date)).weekday()  # 3=Thursday
print verbose_dict[a]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in using a list or a dict :

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', Saturday', 'Sunday']
print 'It\'s %s' % days[a]
```

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary would be the most elegant solution in your case, I guess. If you need a more complex logic instead of a simple mapping, you might think about a switch-statement though.